# mongodb suddenly going to close listening sockets

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, server

I have a ubuntu 16.04 server (1 Core, 2GB RAM) and installed MongoDB v4.2.1 last year. recently having this problem which ***mongod*** service is running but my nodejs apps are crashed. after restarting mongod problem goes away

MongoDB logs:

```
2020-10-03T13:30:15.869+0330 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2020-10-03T13:30:15.887+0330 I  NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-10-03T13:30:15.887+0330 I  NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-2717.sock
2020-10-03T13:30:15.905+0330 I  -        [signalProcessingThread] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-10-03T13:30:15.917+0330 I  FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2020-10-03T13:30:15.930+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Deregistering all the collections
2020-10-03T13:30:15.933+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Timestamp monitor shutting down
2020-10-03T13:30:15.934+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2020-10-03T13:30:15.936+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down session sweeper thread
2020-10-03T13:30:15.936+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
2020-10-03T13:30:15.936+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down journal flusher thread
2020-10-03T13:30:15.986+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Finished shutting down journal flusher thread
2020-10-03T13:30:15.986+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down checkpoint thread
2020-10-03T13:30:15.988+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Finished shutting down checkpoint thread
2020-10-03T13:30:16.338+0330 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2020-10-03T13:30:16.347+0330 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2020-10-03T13:30:16.349+0330 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
2020-10-03T13:30:16.861+0330 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
```

Comment: Any chance you don't have enough actual storage on your machine for everything to run smoothly?

Comment: No, half of the storage is available

Comment: The relevant log entries are likely above what you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

The --fork option can be used only when starting mongod manually, if you are using systemd, for instance, the process turns to a daemon by itself, and the --fork option causes this kind of crash.